# Loop Function VBA

Tags: vba, loops

im trying to do a loop in my vba project. Without Looping its look like this:

```
varia1 = Sess0.Screen.GetString(8, 59, 22)
varia2 = Sess0.Screen.GetString(9, 59, 22)
varia3 = Sess0.Screen.GetString(10, 59, 22)
varia4 = Sess0.Screen.GetString(11, 59, 22)
varia5 = Sess0.Screen.GetString(12, 59, 22)
varia6 = Sess0.Screen.GetString(13, 59, 22)
varia7 = Sess0.Screen.GetString(14, 59, 22)
varia8 = Sess0.Screen.GetString(15, 59, 22)
varia9 = Sess0.Screen.GetString(16, 59, 22)
varia10 = Sess0.Screen.GetString(17, 59, 22)



MsgBox (varia1 & Chr(10) & varia2 & Chr(10) & varia3 & Chr(10) & varia4 & Chr(10) & varia5 & Chr(10) & varia6 & Chr(10) & varia7 & Chr(10) & varia8 & Chr(10) & varia9 & Chr(10) & varia10)
```

What I wanna do is something like this :

```
varia1=""
varia2=""
i = 8
Do While i = 17
    varia2 = Sess0.Screen.GetString(i, 59, 22)
    i = i + 1
    varia1 = "varia1" & "varia2" 
    Loop
MsgBox (varia1)
```

But it does not work, I have only a empty MsgBox at the end.

Comment: Change `Do While i = 17` to `Do While i <= 17`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to loop while i is less than or equal to 17. The loop never runs under your current code.

```
varia1=""
varia2=""
i = 8
Do While i <= 17
    varia2 = Sess0.Screen.GetString(i, 59, 22)
    i = i + 1
    varia1 = "varia1" & "varia2" 
Loop
MsgBox (varia1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're very close. It should look like this:

```
Dim varia1 as String
Dim i As Long
For i = 8 To 17
    varia1 = varia1 & vbCrLf & Sess0.Screen.GetString(i, 59, 22)
Next i
MsgBox varia1
```